# C# Passing Data from project to project

Tags: c#

My Solution has 2 projects:

The first project is a login system where the user logins

I have a variable that holds the id of the actual connected user :

```
public static int UserID;
```

the variable takes a value from the database when the user logins:

```
            User_info.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Table.Rows[0][0]);
            User_info.UserName = Table.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            User_info.Password = Table.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            User_info.Email = Table.Rows[0][3].ToString();
            User_info.Pack = Convert.ToInt32(Table.Rows[0][4]);
            MessageBox.Show("" + User_info.UserID);
```

As you can see the UserID variable takes its value from  a table that holds the full user information.

I checked that the value is not null or 0, it always takes the value of that table.

So in the other project I added the first project as a reference of course and used it:

```
using Bufferz_Server.Network___Acces;
```

So I tried to use the UserID Value in my other project:

```
private int UserID = User_info.UserID;
```

I run the first project and login to set the `UserID` value then I run the other project while the first one is still debbuging.
But I always get the value 0 in the second project 
I don't know if I miss something?

Comment: UserID must be marked as public. Bufferz_Server.Network___Acces must be public, as well.

Comment: I also tried to work with `User_info.UserID` directly but it gives the same value !

Comment: Is this a desktop application?

Comment: @David Tansey Yes sir !

Comment: Are they both user interface projects? You probably just need to create two windows within the same program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explaination:

When you reference "Project 1" in "Project 2" and put `using Bufferz_Server.Network___Acces;` in it, you actually just import code from "Project 1".

You do that to reuse code from other pojects (Usually .dll's).
Afterwards your "Project 2" depends on "Project 1".

**This is just for reusing code! The projects share no memory at all.**

So no variables that come from the process of "Project 1" will ever reach the process of "Project 2" unless you specificly tell "Project 2" or do some kind of memory sharing.

## Solution:

You could use some sort of communication as for example TCP/UDP sockets to send your stuff over to the other process.

**Or**

You can use Memory Mapped Files [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/salvapatuel/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4/) is a guide for that.

I recommend you the latter.

Comment: Hello !  thank you for this answer ! For example if i want to build a the project2 from project 1 and insert something in it ?